# check dupliocate record creation for a week

Tags: apex, trigger

Attaching a piece of code below which checks the creation of one record per day. I want to make this code run for checking the creation of one record for a week. No two records can be created in a week.

```
trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on Time_In__c (before insert) {
      for(Time_In__c a:Trigger.new)
       {
        string uid = userinfo.getName();
         List<Time_In__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Owner.Name, Start_Date_del__c from Time_In__c where (Owner.Name = :uid AND CreatedDate = Today)];
             if(acc.size()>0)
             {
               a.adderror('One record is already created for the Day For ' + uid);
             }
       }
   }
```

Comment: just change the date filter to check in last 7 days, Are you facing any challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on Time_In__c (before insert) {
  for(Time_In__c a:Trigger.new)
   {
    string uid = userinfo.getName();
     List<Time_In__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Owner.Name, Start_Date_del__c from Time_In__c where (Owner.Name = :uid AND CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK)];
         if(acc.size()>0)
         {
           a.adderror('One record is already created for the Day For ' + uid);
         }
   }
```

}

Comment: what chnages could be made to the code such that it allows more than one record in a week but not with the similar Start Date? (more than one records with different start dates)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to get out of the way first...

First, use the user Id, not the user's name. This may cause problems down the road.

Second, do not place a query in a loop, as that can cause large data loads to fail.

Third, you should clarify if you meant the last seven days, or *this week*, which it sounds like what you'd actually want to do.

Given those, here's how we can fix this:

```
trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on Time_In__c (before insert) {
  Set<Id> ownersThisWeek = new Set<Id>();
  Map<Id, Time_In__c> matches = new Map<Id, Time_In__c>();
  // Prevent duplicates in the same trigger //
  for(Time_In__c record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.OwnerId == null) {
      record.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    }
    if(!ownersThisWeek.add(record.OwnerId)) {
      record.addError('You may not have more than one card in a week.');
    } else {
      matches.put(record.OwnerId, record);
    }
  }
  // Check for duplicates in the database
  for(Time_In__c record: [SELECT OwnerId FROM Time_In__c WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK AND OwnerId = :matches.keySet() FOR UPDATE]) {
    Time_In__c newRecord = matches.get(OwnerId);
    if(newRecord != null) {
      newRecord.addError('You may not have more than one card in a week.');
    }
  }
}
```

This change prevents duplicates that may sneak in because of bulk data loads, as well as duplicates from the existing week. Change `THIS_WEEK` to `LAST_N_DAYS:7` if you wish to change the behavior from limiting one record between Sun-Sat to the last seven days.

Comment: what chnages could be made to the code such that it allows more than one record in a week but not with the similar Start Date? (more than one records with different start dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the soql query outside for loop. Try something like below

```
trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on Time_In__c (before insert) {
string uid = userinfo.getName();
integer Max_Records = 1;
List<Time_In__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Owner.Name, Start_Date_del__c from Time_In__c where (Owner.Name = :uid AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7)];
total = acc.size();
  for(Time_In__c a:Trigger.new)
   {
         if(total == Max_Records)
         {
           a.adderror('One record is already created for the Day For ' + uid);
           break;
         }
         else {
             total = total+1;
         }

   } }
```

It's good to Max_records = 1 in the custom setting / custom metadata type and make this as configurable.